# How Select accounts that Meet Both Criteria, Esentially removing the Non-Duplicated Accounts or only Selecting the proper accounts to begin with

Tags: sql

```
SELECT DISTINCT e.account, c.complete, c.value, c.step, r.user
FROM relationship r
LEFT OUTER JOIN entity e ON r.relationshipenid - e.entityid
FULL OUTER JOIN process c ON r.relationshipid = c.processid
WHERE c.step IN ('Verified','Setup')
AND c.complete IN ('Y','Y')
```

This SQL Query gets me mostly the results I want. Though I only want e.account's that meet both the Verified AND Setup. This query is giving me accounts that also meet just Verified OR Setup, and I need both.

Sample Data would be something like
[Image of Sample Tables I am Using and What I want to have Returned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPtay.jpg)

I Did an Image of the tables for examples Copying a Pasting them wasn't showing them correctly.

Comment: That FULL OUTER JOIN isn't executed as one... Replace WHERE with AND and see what happens!

Comment: This did not work, but the answer below did. Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one method if you just want accounts:

```
SELECT e.account
FROM relationship r JOIN
     entity e
     ON r.relationshipenid = e.entityid JOIN
     process c
     ON r.relationshipid = c.processid
WHERE c.step IN ('Verified', 'Setup') AND c.complete IN ('Y', 'Y')
GROUP BY e.account
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT c.step) = 2;
```

Note:  Your outer joins are useless.  The `where` clause turns them into `inner join`s anyway.  Plus, outer joins don't make sense for the question you are asking.